# How to call different post requests when submitting different form inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two inputs with options for each of them. The first one is drug/disease and the second list has a list of drugs and a list of diseases depending on the choice selected for the first list.

I also have nine "cards" with data that is called by post requests. When drugs is selected and submitted, the nine cards submit post requests to drug routes and the drug data appears. When diseases is selected and submitted, the nine cards have different post requests to disease routes. I got the drug cards working, but now I added diseases, and I can't make post requests to the disease cards.

I added an `if` statement saying if the user selected `Drug`, after a submit action, the user will make post requests to `Drug` and after selecting `Disease`, the user will make post requests to `Disease`. HOwever all it does is refresh the page.

The expected results is cards loading with drug data when drug is selected and submitted, and cards loading with disease data when disease is selected and submitted. The Actual result is page refreshing.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <select id="memoryType" class="form-control firstList">
 <option value="select" selected="selected">Select</option>
  <option value="drug">Drug</option>
 <option value="disease">Disease</option>
  </select>
   </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="drugInput" class="form-control search-input secondList">
     <option value="select" selected="selected">...</option>
     </select>
<div class="form-group">
<button class="form-control" id="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

```js
var selectedOption = $('#memoryType option:selected').val();
if (selectedOption.toLowerCase() == "drug") {
  $("#submit").click(function(event) {
    alert("Submitted")
    var text = $("#drugInput option:selected").val();
    var search = JSON.stringify({
      "input": text
    });

    console.log("submit");

    $.post("/L1000", search, function(data) {
      $(".card-1").html(data);
    })

    $.post("/creeds_drugs", search, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $(".card-2").html(data);
    })

    $.post("/creeds_diseases", search, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $(".card-3").html(data);
    })

    $.post("/geneshot", search, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $(".card-4").html(data);
    })

    $.post("/gwas_drugs", search, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $(".card-5").html(data);
    })

    $.post("/x2kl1000", search, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $(".card-7").html(data);
    })

    $.post("/x2k_creeds", search, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $(".card-8").html(data);
    })

    $.post("/L1000_diseases", search, function(data) {
      $(".card-1").html(data);
    })

    event.preventDefault();
  })
} else if (selectedOption.toLowerCase() == 'disease') {
  $("#submit").click(function(event) {
    var text = $("#drugInput option:selected").val();
    var search = JSON.stringify({
      "input": text
    });

    console.log("submit");

    $.post("/L1000_diseases", search, function(data) {
      $(".card-1").html(data);
    })

    $.post("/creeds_dx_dx", search, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $(".card-3").html(data);
    })
    event.preventDefault();
  })
}
```

Comment: Share the html form, issue might be adding `onClick` event to `submit button` , try `$('form').submit()`
and also move `option` condition code inside handler function

Comment: ```<button class="form-control" id="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>``` I tried what you said but it just refreshed the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because your logic is backwards with regard to the `if` statement being outside the `click` handler - as that means it will only ever run when the page loads. You instead need to make that `if` condition check when the `click` happens to know what the currently selected option is.

You're also repeating some common logic in both sides of the `if` statement which can be DRY'd up. Try this:

```js
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var selectedOption = $('#memoryType option:selected').val();
  var text = $("#drugInput option:selected").val();
  var search = JSON.stringify({ "input": text  });

  if (selectedOption.toLowerCase() == "drug") {
    // $.post requests...
  } else if (selectedOption.toLowerCase() == 'disease') {
    // $.post requests...
  }
})
```

However, while that fixes the logic, you should be aware that making that many AJAX requests to your server is bad practice. Given enough concurrent users you would effectively be DDOSing yourself. A *much* better idea, especially given that *all* the requests receive the same data, would be to make a single request and then return all drug/disease/geneshot etc information in that one request.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I did what you said, and that got rid of the refreshing, but it didn't call the post requests and I didn't get an alert that I put in the if and else if statement. I'm not sure what you meant by requests receiving the same data, because each card has different data called. Each card is calling an API in python code and I'm using Flask to return the data as json. I'm not sure how I can make one request. I also added my HTML if you want to debug that.